# can't use method "getString(int resId)" in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

1. I've the following class in my fragment activity now i want to get name of tabs from strings.xml but i can't able to use method `getString(int resId)` it gives a error message "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context".
2. In method `public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` I need to get like this `name = getString(R.string.mystring)` any help is appreciated.

> ```
> public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>
>           public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
>               super(fm);
>           }
>
>           @Override
>           public Fragment getItem(int i) {
>               switch (i) {
>               case 0:
>                   Fragment fragment = new Activity1();
>                   return fragment;
>
>               case 1:
>                   Fragment fragment1 = new Activity2();
>                   return fragment1;
>
>               default:
>                   return new Activity2();
>               }
>           }
>
>           @Override
>           public int getCount() {
>               return 2;
>           }
>
>           public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
>               String name = null;
>               if (position==0) {
>                   name = "Movie Details";
>               }else if (position==1) {
>                   name = "Movie Comments";
>               }
>               return name;
>           }
>       }
> ```

Comment: you will need activity context to call `getString`. Also is it an inner class your `AppSectionsPagerAdapter`?

Comment: @Raghunandan how to do that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a `Context` object to call `getResources().getString(int resID)`. Try passing a `Context` in your constructor and using it here like

```
Context mContext;

public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
          super(fm);
           mContext = context
      }
```

and then use `mContext.getResources().getString(int resID)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `static` keyword from your class definition if it's an inner class.

EDIT: Don't do this--see comment below.

Comment: Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don’t control their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference to the activity inside. http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/